# infinite number of tosses of a fair coin. The probability of heads equals tails.

Tags: probability

So carried to infinity does the fact of equal probabilities for head and tails make the particular random walk from these tosses go to zero.  In other words will the walk tend to zero distance at infinity because the flips obey the probabilities of the fair coin.

Comment: You have not actually asked a question, but I would argue that your statement is false: the probability that the number of heads equals the number of tails (after an even number of tosses) tends towards zero as the number of tosses increases without limit.

Comment: It's hard for me to explain. I am asking if one can state that a binary random walk starting at zero will at an infinite number of tosses end at zero because the statistics say that an equal number of heads and an equal number of tails will have occurred for a fair coin.

Comment: Where do the statistics say that?  The law of large numbers says that the proportion of heads and the proportion of tails will both converge on $\frac12$ in this example, but the central limit theorem says that the numbers of each will almost surely not be equal.

Comment: Not even at infinity.  Just asking.  BTW thanks.

Comment: Very nice intuition @Henry. Do you mind elaborating on the central limit theorem part as to why the numbers will almost surely not be equal?

Comment: After a million, the difference will probably be in the thousands; after a trillion, the difference will probably be in the millions.  It's around the square-root of the number of tosses.

Comment: The walk doesn’t “end” anywhere if it keeps on going. Furthermore, I think that for an infinite random walk of left-right steps from the origin, the walker travels arbitrarily far away from the origin (in both directions) with probability $1$ (and also returns to the origin infinitely often with probability $1$).

Comment: The $\sqrt n$ is the root mean square distance after $n$ tosses. Thanks for helping @Michael

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_n$ be an iid sequence of random variables with $$\mathbb P(X_1) = p = 1-\mathbb P(X_1) = 0. $$
Set $\bar X_n = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then
$$\mu:=\mathbb E[\bar X_n] = \mathbb E\left[\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] = \frac1n\cdot np = p. $$
The strong law of large numbers tells us that
$$\mathbb P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} |\bar X_n-\mu| = 0\right). $$
Hence $\bar X_n$ converges to zero almost surely (and therefore in probability and in distribution), but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb E[\bar X_n] = p>0$ so $\bar X_n$ does not converge in $L^p$ for $p\geqslant 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I kind of understood what you are trying to ask but can't quite rephrase it. If you are talking about the markov chain and want to know that eventually there are equal number of heads and tails on an average, then the answer is yes. Let $X_i$ be a random variable such that $X_i = 1$ if $i^{th}$ toss is heads else $X_i = 0$. Then $E(X) = \sum E(X_i) = 0$. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: You probably intended to say "... else $X_i =-1$".  But in any case I thing that the question was more like saying that if $Y_n = \sum_1^n X_i$ then does $P(Y_n=0) \to 1$ as $n\to \infty$?  to which the answer is "no, $P(Y_n=0) \to 0$."

Comment: Yes Henry this was the question.  And I think you are correct. Math1000 considered the average but my interest is in the question as you phrased it.